# Unable to start AWS EC2 instance with deltacloud

Tags: ruby, apache, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cloud

I am trying to manage a EC2 cloud instance with [deltacloud API through curl](https://deltacloud.apache.org/curl-examples.html). With the mock driver everything works fine: deltacloudd -i mock -r 10.0.0.3

```
curl --user "mockuser:mockpassword" "http://10.0.0.3:3001/api/instances?format=xml"
curl -X POST --user "mockuser:mockpassword" "http://10.0.0.3:3001/api/instances/inst1/stop?format=xml"
```

But with EC2 I am unable to start a stopped instance: **deltacloudd -i ec2 -P eu-west-1 -r 10.0.0.3 -V**

```
curl --user "accesskey:secretaccesskey" "http://10.0.0.3:3001/api/instances?format=xml"
curl -X POST --user "accesskey:secretaccesskey" "http://10.0.0.3:3001/api/instances/i-NNNNNNNN/start?format=xml"
```

Returns: **The required capability to execute this operation is missing**

Deltacloud log output:

```
Listening on 10.0.0.3:3001, CTRL+C to stop
D, [2014-06-25T10:47:34.149001 #3575] DEBUG -- : New Aws::Ec2 using per_thread-connection mode
D, [2014-06-25T10:47:34.150897 #3575] DEBUG -- : Opening new HTTPS connection to ec2.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com:443
10.0.0.5 - - [25/Jun/2014 10:47:34] "GET /api/instances?format=xml HTTP/1.1" ec2 eu-west-1 200 1628 0.6204
10.0.0.5 - - [25/Jun/2014 10:48:14] "POST /api/instances/i-NNNNNNNN/start?format=xml {} HTTP/1.1" ec2 eu-west-1 412 60 0.0077
```

Its therefore obvious that deltacloud process GET, but **not forward the POST request to AWS**.

The Problem also happens even by clicking the start button at the webinterface (10.0.0.3:3001). The accesskey and secretaccesskey are working fine with python-boto.

Can anyone suggest me whats wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is, that you [can not start a stopped Amazon EC2 instance](http://deltacloud.apache.org/drivers.html#drivers) with deltacloud in the current version 1.1.3 (2013-04-17). Perhaps there will be soon a newer version, but since Red Hat [reduced their support](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/deltacloud-dev/201305.mbox/%3C518D0F79.4000901%40redhat.com%3E) the [development of deltacloud](https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=deltacloud.git;a=shortlog) slowed down.